# Error Changing Page Content Using Session Values

Tags: php, session, isset

My goal is to change the content in header file using session variables.
The scenario is:

1. In index.php,next to the Login button(this button is located at header.php) there is a text "Login first".
2. Login
3. Redirect to index.php but in header the text next to login button will be changed to "User is: " . $_SESSION['u_id'] . "now"". (e.g User is Paul now)

Any ideas?The login is working but the content is not changed.Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]: Problem is solved! I forgot to declare variable $row ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); )

index.php file:

```
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
?>

.
.
.
```

header.php file:

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>  

.
.
. 

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['u_id']))
{
   echo  "User is: " . $_SESSION['u_first'] . "now" ;
}
else
{
   echo "Login first";
}
?>
```

login.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' AND user_pwd = '$pwd' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck < 1)
{
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
else
{
    //LOGIN
    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];

    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
    exit();
}

}
else
{
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What issue you are getting? It's not clear.

Comment: It's not changing the text... Before the login i have [LOGIN BUTTON] Login first and after the login and the redirection i have [LOGIN BUTTON] Login first... But i expect [LOGIN BUTTON] User is Paul now

Comment: Are you talking about Login first text that coming in if condition based on $_SESSION['u_id']

Comment: Yes! I want to change the text content...but is not changing

Comment: before the if condition, have you debug it. Check $_SESSION['u_id'] is coming or not like echo  $_SESSION['u_id']; die;

Comment: Also check for: echo $_SESSION['u_first']; die; I don't think its coming.

Comment: Debug it step by step, data seems to be not coming in your Session variable.

Comment: It remains empty...I typed: echo 'u_first is, '.$_SESSION['u_first']; but the variable is empty...

Comment: then check where you are setting it. Check here: $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];

Comment: make sure $row['user_first'] is not coming as empty

Comment: If it is coming then check at top of index.php file after include_once 'header.php'; like echo $_SESSION['u_first']; die;

Comment: Found it!!! At login.php file i was missing this : $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: That's nice! I think so, you are missing something somewhere..